# Copy and Paste the text (Android App)

Tags: android, service, clipboardmanager

I am building ClipboardManager app which is used for copying the text and pasting to the app. I used OnPrimaryClipChangedListener to listen the text that is copied to clipboard and I run OnPrimaryClipChangedListener on app service and that will paste the text automatically to my app. But the problem is that when I open ClipboardManager app and copy the text from own app, it again trigger OnPrimaryClipChangedListener and paste the data again. How to filter the text that is copied from ClipboardManager app or any other app? If that copied from our own app then discard else save the data to ClipboardManager  database.

Comment: you need root access.

Comment: My phone is not rooted, but some other app related to clipboardmanager work perfectly.. While text copy from any browser it will trigger app and save that text automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private OnPrimaryClipChangedListener listener = new OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
    public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
        performClipboardCheck();
    }
};

private void performClipboardCheck {
    ClipboardManager cb = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        if (cb.hasPrimaryClip()) {
            ClipData cd = cb.getPrimaryClip();
            cd.getItemAt(0).getText()
        }
};
```

from [Permanently listen to Clipboard changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22277598)

That is probably what you want, that also means this is a duplicate...

Comment: I will try it. Thanks for you help.