# broadcast receiver doesn't work when my application is NOT running

Tags: java, android, broadcast

My broadcast receiver worked but only when my application is running...
When I close the program, the broadcast receiver will not work anymore.

My codes:

GetClipboard.java

```
public class GetClipboard extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle!=null) {
            try {

                final ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                assert clipboardManager != null;
                clipboardManager
                        .addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
                                ClipData clipData = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip();
                                final String data = clipData.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
                                Toast.makeText(context,data, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:name=".GetClipboard">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.content.Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE" />
    </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```

**build.gradle**

```
compileSdkVersion 27
minSdkVersion 19
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Comment: That is the expected behavior

Comment: Note that apps targetting api level 26 or later can no longer register implicit broadcast receivers - https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html

Answer (score 0):

`BroadCastReceivers` lifecycles are only as long as the application exists. It won't work if you close the app. If you want to be notified when the app is closed, investigate `AlarmManagers`

Comment: So how should I understand when something copied in clipboard or receive sms when my app not runing

Comment: PushNotifications maybe ? Clipboard changes I think you need to use a service. Check it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277598/permanently-listen-to-clipboard-changes

Comment: My application will only run once and will never be opened ..Must work in the background,can start service one time for ever? I want to get sms,clipboard service,incoming call,outgoing call..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `service` to run the app goes close/background.Because unbinds the receiver

Refer this sample

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16824692/3505534